# button class creates another screen to show buttons instead of displaying on exisiting screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a screen in pygame and want to display command buttons on it. for that i have written a code containing button class but it creates another screen instead of displaying the buttons on the same screen. can anyone tell me where i have gone wrong?

```py
# import the pygame module
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
width, height =1550,800
fps = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
font=pygame.font.SysFont('arial',40)
objects = []
pygame.display.set_caption('image')
imp=pygame.image.load("D:/PycharmProjects/flay high bangtan/flappy bird\sprites/background/main page.jpg")
screen.blit(imp,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
status=True
while (status):
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            status=False


#COMMAND BUTTONS
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, buttonText='Button', onclickFunction=None, onePress=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.onclickFunction = onclickFunction
        self.onePress = onePress

        self.fillColors = {
            'normal': '#ffffff',
            'hover': '#666666',
            'pressed': '#333333',
        }

        self.buttonSurface = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.buttonRect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

        self.buttonSurf = font.render(buttonText, True, (20, 20, 20))

        self.alreadyPressed = False

        objects.append(self)

    def process(self):

        mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        self.buttonSurface.fill(self.fillColors['normal'])
        if self.buttonRect.collidepoint(mousePos):
            self.buttonSurface.fill(self.fillColors['hover'])

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed(num_buttons=3)[0]:
                self.buttonSurface.fill(self.fillColors['pressed'])

                if self.onePress:
                    self.onclickFunction()

                elif not self.alreadyPressed:
                    self.onclickFunction()
                    self.alreadyPressed = True

            else:
                self.alreadyPressed = False

        self.buttonSurface.blit(self.buttonSurf, [
            self.buttonRect.width / 2 - self.buttonSurf.get_rect().width / 2,
            self.buttonRect.height / 2 - self.buttonSurf.get_rect().height / 2
        ])
        screen.blit(self.buttonSurface, self.buttonRect)


def myFunction():
    print('Button Pressed')


customButton = Button(30, 30, 400, 100, 'PLAY', myFunction)
customButton = Button(30, 140, 400, 100, 'ABOUT US', myFunction)
customButton = Button(30, 250, 400, 100, 'EXIT', myFunction)

# Game loop.
while True:
    screen.fill((20, 20, 20))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    for object in objects:
        object.process()

    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsClock.tick(fps)
pygame.QUIT()
```

this is code to create a screen in pygame and display buttons on it. but when i run it i get one screen that shows my image and after closing it i get another screen with buttons. but i am not understanding how to put those buttons on the same screen as that of the iamge.

Comment: Hello, you call two while loop. The first, when program starts with image and the second, when you break the first one. Delete the first while loop and add screen.blit function with image to the second while loop. I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 application loops. Remove the 1st application loop, but draw the background image in the second application loop:

```py
# DELETE
#screen.blit(imp,(0,0))
#pygame.display.flip()
#status=True
#while (status):
#    for i in pygame.event.get():
#        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
#            status=False

# [...]

# Game loop.
while True:
    
    # DELETE
    # screen.fill((20, 20, 20))
    
    # INSERT
    screen.blit(imp,(0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    for object in objects:
        object.process()

    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsClock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```